# Razor - output single quote

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In a .NET 4.5 / MVC 5.1.2 project, I am trying to write inside a JavaScript tag using this Razor syntax:

```
@string.Join(",", ((IEnumerable<JqGridColumn>)ViewBag.JqGridColumns)
    .Select(p => Html.Raw("'" + p.Name + "'")))
```

Expected output:

```
'Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3', ...
```

Actual output:

```
&#39;Col 1&#39;,&#39;Col 2&#39;,&#39;Col 3&#39;, ...
```

How can I output a single quote character using the Razor syntax above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put the `Html.Raw` around the `string.Join` and not in the `Select`:

```
@Html.Raw(string.Join(",", ((IEnumerable<JqGridColumn>)ViewBag.JqGridColumns)
    .Select(p => "'" + p.Name + "'")))
```

Because the `string.Join` always returns a plain `string` even if you concatenated `Html.Raw` strings so you need to apply the `Html.Raw` after you have created your joined string.